# phantomJS how to get answer from JS scripts which starting after the page have loaded

Tags: javascript, json, response, phantomjs, pageload

I'm looking for a solution for that question.

The site load several JS scripts after page have loaded, it's working well, the page get the response from the scripts and render it to site page.

But the scripts return JSON and I want to get this response in JSON, not from generated page. It's a more faster to use the script's answer than use selectors and cycles for get the information from page.

I try to use `page.onResourceReceived()` but it's get me only analytics information, filenames stock and response sizes;

How can I get the body of this response ?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your requirement correctly, you may try using window.callPhantom at the web page end to pass the data as an Object and receive the data through page.onCallback eventlistener at PhantomJS scope.

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html

Excerpt:

This callback is invoked when there is a JavaScript window.callPhantom call made on the web page. The only argument passed to the callback is a data object.

Note: window.callPhantom is still an experimental API. In the near future, it will be likely replaced with a message-based solution which will still provide the same functionality.

Although there are many possible use cases for this inversion of control, the primary one so far is to prevent the need for a PhantomJS script to be continually polling for some variable on the web page.

Example:
WebPage (client-side)

```
if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
    window.callPhantom({ hello: 'world' });
}
```

PhantomJS (server-side)

```
page.onCallback = function(data) {
    console.log('CALLBACK: ' + JSON.stringify(data));  // Prints 'CALLBACK: { "hello":     "world" }'
};
```

Additionally, note that the WebPage#onCallback handler can return a data object that will be carried back as the result of the originating window.callPhantom call, too.

Example:

WebPage (client-side)

```
if (typeof window.callPhantom === 'function') {
    var status = window.callPhantom({ secret: 'ghostly' });
    alert(status);  // Will either print 'Accepted.' or 'DENIED!'
}
```

PhantomJS (server-side)

```
page.onCallback = function(data) {
    if (data && data.secret && data.secret === 'ghostly') {
        return 'Accepted.';
    }
    return 'DENIED!';
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't edit these pages on server side. I need to get the data in JSON from scripts which the page launch .

Comment: @llya,  The "Client-Side" javascript is run on in the context of the page when calling one of the `page.evaluate` functions, as in `page.evaluate(function(){console.log("This is running in the context of the page");});`